Older sci-fi cartoon with a robot boy character that is green, magenta and silver
There is a TV show I watched on DVD when I was a kid that I cannot remember at all now. It was probably around 2013-2014, but came out in the 90s I am guessing by the art style. I believe it was hand drawn.
It consists of a crew that is trying to save their world and selves from these bad guys. There is an episode where they work to save from a big, yellow orange planet from getting too dangerously close to them.
The main thing I remember it this one robot character. He is human-shaped and is green, magenta and silver. He is smart and able to extend wires and tubes from his head; I remember one scene where he extends them into different sections of the ship to save it.

Could it be Exosquad ? Can you try to look up, could you give us a time frame, please

Why do you think it’s Exosquad?  Could you [edit] in some matching details from the question? A synopsis could be helpful.

Definitely in the 1990s ish.
